# How to cut down train error for a dense-matrix factorization task?

Tags: machine-learning

This problem may seem very different from the **normal Matrix Factorization** task which is widely used in recommender system.

My problem is described as below:

Given a **dense** Matrix M

(approximately 55000*200, may contain much negative elements, 0.1< abs(M[i][j]) <1 )

I have to find two matrix A(55000*1400) and B(1400*200), such that:

AB=M

However, we have some knowledge about A. We have another Matrix C, if C[i][j] = 0, then A[i][j] **must be zero**, otherwise it can be any value(C[i][j] = 1).

In my practice , I use **machine learning** to solve the problem, my loss function is:

||(A*C)(element-wise product) x B - M ||(2)(L2 norm)

I have tried **adagrad,momentum,adadelta** and some other optimization method, but the train error is pretty much and is cut down slowly (learning_rate = 0.1)

**UP1**:
Well, actually I've got a machine with 32GB memory and I only need 2 min for each epoch. I decompose an element in M only if its corresponding element in C is anotated as 1. Practically , I only decompose M[i][j] when C[i][j] = 1, and after I decompose M[i][j], I solve the gradient for M[i][j] to update A[i : ] and B[ : j] **at once**. So, the batch I used is too small--just contain one element.  Also , I have to mention that C is a pretty sparse matrix. For each line in C, there is only 2-3 elements that are anotated as 1.

Comment: Tune your hyper-parameters (yes, learning-rate too) and also try pure SGD. Of course batch-methods and batch-based 2nd-order methods also have some merrit, if you got enough memory. ```m, n, o = 33000, 120, 840``` takes 10 min on my sys (```x0: 10^3, x_final: 10-8```and uses already 9 GB), with sub-par automatic-differentiation used. But scaling to your numbers would be costly. One additional potential advantage of these methods: line-search is used = less tuning-hassle. How did you incorporate the A<->C fix when using unconstrained optimization as it seems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After struggling with it for nearly half month, I finally got the answer: I should update the matrix A much more quickly, say, update the parameters at a more smaller step. I originally updated every element in A only once per epoch, much less than B. However, after I changed the code to let A be updated at the same speed as B, then surprise happened: it worked pretty well!

Maybe smaller steps will help SGD work better? I don't really believe it mathematically.